# Данные из строки

Tags: java

У меня есть строка, в ней записаны слова через запятую и перед некоторыми стоит точка(без пробела между словом и точкой), например так:

```
"Apple, .Orange, Grapes, .Cherry, .Coal"
```

Нужно взять из строки слова(возможно и два слова подряд между которыми будет пробел), стоящие между точкой и запятой, и добавить в массив. Также нужно учесть что последнее слово не оканчивается на запятую.

Не знаю как сделать попроще на Java под Android(желательно обратно совместимо с обычной Java), чтобы не городить велосипед. Буду благодарен посильной помощи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая регулярка найдет все, что нужно:

```
\.(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

Результаты:

- `"Apple, .Orange, Grapes, .Cherry, .Coal"` => `["Orange", "Cherry", "Coal"]`
- `".Apple, Orange, Grapes, Cherry, .Coal"` => `["Apple", "Coal"]`
- `"Apple, .Orange juice, Grapes, Cherry, .Coal"` => `["Orange juice", "Coal"]`

---

Как это работает?

- Искомый фрагмент - это произвольный набор символов, начинающийся с точки `\.(.*?)`. Ленивый квантификатор `*?` не даст регулярке съесть все до конца строки.
- Признак окончания фрагмента - запятая или конец строки `,|$`. Чтобы сам признак окончания не попадал в результаты поиска - завернем его в `(?:  )`, получаем `(?:,|$)`

Comment: Ругается на "\."

"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Comment: Ну дык я привёл сырой регэксп. В реалиях java само собой надо отбить слэш: `"\\.(.*?)(?:,|$)"`

Comment: Выдает всю последующую строку после последнего слова перед которым стоит точка(само слово с точкой не берет)

Взял так: String[] GenreTagsArray = Genretext.split("\\.(.*?)(?:,|$)");

Comment: Так это не для split-а регулярка, а для поиска

Comment: Спасибо вроде работает, но вот точки и запятые оставляет с краев, не пойму почему

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "Apple,.Orange, Grapes,.Cherry,.Coal";
String[] parts = string.split(",.");
```

Comment: А как быть с последним словом?

Comment: @РоманВасильев, а в чем проблема с последним словом?

Comment: Оно не оканчивается на точку, т.е. не подойдет под условие которое вырежет и добавит ее в массив

Comment: Но перед ним есть `,.`, значит все хорошо.

Comment: Ладно, попробую - отпишусь, а то мне что-то кажется немного не то

Comment: А как насчет первого слова, если перед ним будет точка?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте метод [String.split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)(","), где в параметре метода укажите какой именно знак служит разделителем между словами. Метод возвращает массив String